# How to convert Strings to numbers and then perform addition on them

Tags: java, android, string, math, textview

I am trying to find a way to take a `String` from a `NumberPicker`, and then perform addition on it. If the user selects 5 on the `NumberPicker`, I want to do `(5 + 10)`, then display the results in a `TextView`. I'm looking for examples of how to do this.  I cannot seem to find a easy way to get this done.

Here is some code I'm using.

```
  np5.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener()
        {
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, 
                                      int newVal)
            {
                current_weight_view.setText(String.valueOf(newVal));                    
            }        
        });
```

Comment: `...setText((newVal+10)).toString())` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

> However I need to make it so when the user selects
>   1 it adds 10, not 11 and when the user select 2 it equals 20. and so
>   on.

How about multiplying?

```
 np5.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener()
        {
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, 
                int newVal)
            {
             //10 * 0 = 0;
             //10 * 1 = 10;
             //10 * 2 = 20;
             //etc
                current_weight_view.setText("" + (newVal * 10)); 
            }        
        });
```

And silly me forgetting the brackets earlier:I

Comment: This simply adds 10 to end of the number, so value 1 is 110 and value 2 is 210 and so on. Thanks for the code. It works putting () between the newVal and + 10

Comment: That was silly of me to forget the brackets. I updated my answer with the comment you gave Krrishnaaaa.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add a number to the number selected in `NumberPicker` then

```
np5.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener()
        {
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, 
                int newVal)
            {
                current_weight_view.setText("" + (newVal + 10)); 
            }        
        });
```

Comment: This works for me, However I need to make it so when the user selects 1 it adds 10, not 11 and when the user select 2 it equals 20. and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(str)+Integer.parseInt(str2))
```

…should add the 2 numbers.